# how to authenticate an admin and user in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i am using cakephp framework for my project. but problem is that in my project there are four users like admin,user,employer,bla bla.if all are simultaneously login than how can i authenticate them to right access. so plz help me.....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the Auth component. Have a look on the manual page, http://book.cakephp.org/view/172/Authentication

Then, what I tend to use is in my `Users` table, I'll add a column, `permissions` or similar, and then add in the user type to this column.

Then you can use the `isAuthorized()` function in your `app_controller.php` to check the levels for various controller actions.

There are lots of possible ways of achieving this, you could even use the ACL if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

By default CakePHP uses a model like User fro Auth component. You can use this model for one type of users, and different Models for rest of the user types... This way all types of users can login to your site simultaneously, from a single machine. If you don't do this, only one type of users can login at a time.

Comment: Sorry I meant 'sessionKey', not 'model' in above comment.

Demo? nope I can't. I don't know your level of understanding of Cake but you need to learn about Auth component from the link already provided. After that do this in beforeFilter() of AppController

if($user_type=='admin')
{
 $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'admin_after_login', 'action' => 'index', 'admin'=>true);
 $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout', 'admin'=>true);
 $this->Auth->sessionKey = 'Admin';
 
 $this->layout = "admin";
}

See sessionKey above? its important.

Comment: In **Cake 2** sessionKey is a static prperty, so it [could not be changed](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2207-authcomponentsessionkey-property-cannot-be-changed) as `$this->Auth->sessionKey = "Anything"`. You should change it as `AuthComponent::$sessionKey = "Anything";`